# Removing ndarray from list in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

Very strange issue, giving you details for you to reproduce.

I have an ndarray `x = [[  58.0376135 ], [4739.44845915]]` which is defined as ndarray size (2,1)

I also have this list

```
lst = [array([[11120.19965669],[ 1036.7331153 ]]), 
       array([[  58.0376135 ],[4739.44845915]]), 
       array([[ 766.38433838],[5524.3418457 ]])]
```

list of (2,1) ndarrays. As you can see, `x == lst[1]`.

However, when I write `lst.remove(x)` or `x in lst` I get value error that the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Strangely, on other examples it does work.

How can I make it work here too?

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it:

```
[arr for arr in lst if not np.all(x==arr)]
```

Since `x` is multidimensional you need to use `np.all()` instead of element-wise comparisons like `x in arr`

Comment: Though with float arrays we usually recommend the `np.allclose` test.

Answer (score 0):

For a NumPy array `arr`, the expression `arr in seq` returns the element-wise `in seq` operation, i.e., an array of booleans.

If the resulting array has only one element, then the expression is evaluated as `True` or `False` depending on the boolean value of that element. However, whenever you try to evaluate an array with more than one element in boolean context you get a `ValueError`, as in this case the truth value is ambiguous. You can remove ambiguity through `any` or `all`. Run this code to convince yourself:

```py
In [1282]: x = np.array([0])

In [1283]: y = np.array([0, 1])

In [1284]: bool(x)
Out[1284]: False

In [1285]: bool(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1285-c0cc820b77c4>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(y)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()


In [1286]: any(y)
Out[1286]: True

In [1287]: all(y)
Out[1287]: False
```

If you want to check whether an array is contained in a list you could use NumPy's [`array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) like this:

```py
In [1295]: def array_in_list(arr, alist):
      ...:     for item in alist:
      ...:         if np.array_equal(arr, item):
      ...:             return True
      ...:     return False

In [1296]: array_in_list(x, lst)
Out[1296]: True

In [1297]: array_in_list(2*x, lst)
Out[1297]: False
```

It may be convenient to replace `array_equal` by [`allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose) in order to avoid the issues associated to floating point comparison.